# A SQL query to show a list of sequences that have N occurrences of specific sequence

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need to retrieve a list of sequences that contains a minimum of N occurrences of the numbers of the one specific sequence (the order doesn't matter).

For example:

In my dbtable I have 3 sequences (rows) in 5 integer columns. Ranges are from 0 to 99:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
-- -- -- -- --
 1 56 10 58 70
 6  8  7 50 87
91 78 15 56 01
```

I have one specific integer sequence of 5 numbers like:

```
 1 10 56 78 12
```

If I ask the sequences contained in my DB that have minimal 2 occurrences, I should receive:

```
 1 56 10 58 70 (1,56,10 coincided)
91 78 15 56  1 (1,56 coincided)
```

If I ask the sequences contained in my DB that have minimal 3 occurrences, I will receive:

```
 1 56 10 58 70 (1,56,10 coincided)
```

I need a SQL query for this, somebody can help me?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You should be more specific about the structure. How are those sequences stored you assume ? 5 Columns ? as an array column ? String value ?

Comment: the structure is 5 columns

Comment: Is there a range to the numbers and what data type do they have? You now show all 2 digits-numbers, even with leading zeroes, which makes me suspect they're strings not numbers. ALWAYS SHOW YOUR TABLE STRUCTURE for questions like this. If you want help, write good questions. Note the edit history for your question, that's work you should've done.

Comment: Excuse me for not being so specific.
The range of numbers: 0 to 99. The datatype: integer

Comment: The term "sequence" implies that the order of the number matters, but this is not the case. You have just sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Jan Doggen's idea, but strings are not necessary because the values can be compared directly with [IN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op).
The result of a boolean expression (like `x IN (...)`) is 0 or 1, so it can be summed directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM WhateverThatSuperSecretTableNameIs
WHERE ( 1 IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)) +
      (10 IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)) +
      (56 IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)) +
      (78 IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)) +
      (12 IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5))   >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code because I don't have the SQLite expertise to quickly whip up the complete SQL statement

1)
First convert to a 14 digit string:
select inttostr(c1)+' '+inttostr(c2)+' '+inttostr(c3)+' '+inttostr(c4)+' '+inttostr(c5) as strvalue from dbtable
(so the inttostr should make a two digit string: 0 -> '00')

Do the same with your (5) search integers i1..i5

2)
From that set, select the `(position of i1 in strvalue) mod 3` - it is 1 when i1 is found

3)
You can sum these 5 'positions' and the sum must be >= N